# Mediator template to perform typecasting

Tags: c++, templates, observer-pattern

I'm evaluating implementation strategies for the observer pattern, and one of the requirements is for the base `Subject` class to reach a method in a derived (concrete) class of an `Event` class.

In a prototype implementation I have reached this code in the concrete event class:

```
// a concrete event
class evZoom : public AbstractEvent
{
public:
    virtual void Fill( Subject *aZoomManager)
    {
        mRatio = dynamic_cast<ZoomManager *>(aZoomManager)->mRatio;
    }

    int mRatio;
};
```

Now I am bothered by the fact that each concreate event will have to perform this type cast.

In other words, I care for code simplicity and shortness, where I'd rather concrete classes (of which there are many) to have more elegant code, traded with a more complex base class code (for which there is one).

So the solution I came up with is to use a mediator (ie, one between the base class and the concrete class) template to do the typecasting.

The full implementation looks like so:

```
// For Dec
class Subject;

// A non template abstract base class for the Subject class to work with.
class AbstractEvent
{
public:
    virtual void Fill ( Subject *aSubject ) = 0;
};

// A mediator class to do the type casting
template < class TSubject >
class Event : public AbstractEvent
{
public:
    // This is where we do the type cast.
    virtual void Fill ( Subject *aSubject )
    {
        TSubject *iSubject = dynamic_cast<TSubject *>(aSubject);
        // Somehow the compiler knows to call the abstract method below, but if
        // we change its name we'll get an infinite loop - cranky.
       Fill( iSubject );
    }

    // And a new abstract method to be implemented by concrete events.
    virtual void Fill ( TSubject *aSubject ) = 0;
};

// The subject base class
class Subject
{
public:
    // virtual destructor to make this class polymorphic 
    // so we can cast it dynamically.
    virtual ~Subject() { }

    void Subscribe( AbstractEvent *aEvent )
    {
        aEvent->Fill( this );
    }
};

// A concrete subject class.
class ZoomManager : public virtual Subject
{
public:
    int mRatio;
};

// The concrete event
class evZoom : public Event< ZoomManager >
{
public:
    virtual void Fill( ZoomManager *aZoomManager )
    {
        mRatio = aZoomManager->mRatio;
    }

    int mRatio;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ZoomManager iZoomManager;
    evZoom      *iEvent = new evZoom();

    iZoomManager.Subscribe( iEvent );

    return 0;
}
```

The only problem with this is that I have a gut feeling that there is a better solution; largely as I don't recall ever seeing a mediator class like the one above in any source or library - but could be my inexperience.

Could someone advise on a better solution to the one above?

Comment: Is `ZoomManager` the only type you are expecting on `Fill()`? Why not change the signature of the method?

Comment: No - there might be many concrete subjects: ZoomManager, ScrollManager, Composite, etc.

Comment: Are you just trying to do a switch of all the possible types? If so it calls for double dispatch. `dynamic_cast` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'switch of all the possible types', but there are hundrads of concrete subjects and as this is part of a framework, an application using it might add a few hundrads more - all unknown to the framework itself. Would this rule out double dispatch?

Comment: What I mean is that on `Fill` you seem to be expecting a `ZoomManager` every time, either that or you have a switch (cases for every one of them) that decide what to do with other concrete types.

Comment: This is just a sample code and in practice the base classes go into the core of a framework, various concrete subjects into higher layers, and an application will and more subjects. `ZoomManager` was just given as an example, being one of many concrete subjects. A switch (or a visitor) won't work here as there are too many concrete subjects (to which an application can add).

Comment: Perhaps regardless, adding a switch will involve more code lines that simply adding `<ZoomManager>` to the line `class evZoom : public Event`.

Comment: Definitely, I wasn't suggesting to use a switch, but I guess I am confused with the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: It looks like double dispatch *might* be what you want - Modern C++ Design details a way to do this although I think I've seen better implementations around the interwebs.